# Portable and sturdy tripod

Tags: long-exposure, tripod, manfrotto

I do mostly long exposure architectural photography.

I've always used the Manfrotto Befree tripod, which is great because it can fit a messenger bag and I can carry it everywhere.

I am interested about more sturdy tripods. However, they do not usually fit a messenger bag. I'd like to know if any of you know about a heavier tripod that can fit a messenger bag.

I don't much care about weight. All I care about is being able to fit it in a messenger bag.

Comment: if you've got any reason to rate this question negative, please, explain.

Comment: It seems to be a *shopping question*, which are generally not well received here and are specifically off-topic across most of the SE network.

Comment: What elevation do you require? My photo kit includes a 20lb barbell weight with threads cut into it for black pipe. I've got a tripod head mounted on a black pipe flange and can fit the appropriate length of pipe between them. It is extremely stable up to 16 inches tall but I usually use it with a 6 inch section of pipe.

Comment: I'll assume you mean fit **in** a messenger bag, and not the other way around?

Comment: Messenger bags come in various sizes. I've got an XL version from Timbuk2 that could easily hold a small child, but some are quite small. It'd be helpful if you specified the size limit in inches or centimeters, because we don't know what size your bag is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy with the tripod you use, you may consider stabilizing it rather than replacing it. A tripod is stabilized by adding a weight well below the CG of the system. Some tripods may include a hook at the bottom of the center column. These hooks are often spring loaded and have a maximum weight rating that will be listed in the owner's manual.

If you wish to add more stabilizing weight than recommended for your included hook, or if you do not have one included, you can either [add a hook](http://www.instructables.com/id/Tripod-stabilizer-weight-hook/) or attach a weight to each leg. This can be done by applying wrist/ankle weights meant for humans, or by tying rope or twine around each leg just above the bottom leg lock and attaching a weight to each one.

[image]
Source: Digital Photo Magazine

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to the tripod section of B&H's website: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Complete-Tripods-with-Heads/ci/2635/N/4075788742

Scroll down on the left and you will see an option to filter the results to just those with specific sizes when folded.